# Fourier transform of a function defined on a smooth surface in Rd

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I have a function $f$ defined on a $C^2$-boundary of a bounded open subset $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, with
$$\int_{\partial D}|f|d\sigma<\infty,$$
$d\sigma$ denoting the surface measure. Does it make sense to define the Fourier transform of $f$ as
$$\hat{f}(\omega):=\int_{\partial D}f(y)e^{-2\pi i y\cdot \omega}d\sigma(y)?$$
If so, is $\omega$ in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or just some subset of it?

Comment: What you have written is the Fourier transform of the measure $f\,d\sigma$, which is a perfectly legitimate object.  And this is indeed defined for all $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$.